# (Non-unique) Inverse of some row-wise dot product operations?

Tags: linear-algebra

### Abstracted Version

We wish to find a (non-unique) inverse to the operation: $c_{ij} = a_i \cdot b_j \cdot a_i$

where a is an {M,3} matrix and b is an {N,3,3} matrix. i.e given a numerical matrix c of dimensions {M,N}, find any two arrays a (dimensions {M,3}) and b (dimensions {N,3,3}) to reproduce it

### Mathematica Lingo

Suppose I have an operation which computes row-wise dot products like so:

```
{n, m} = {3, 2};
arrayA = Array[a, {m, 3}];
arrayB = Array[b, {n, 3, 3}];
resultingArray =Simplify[Table[arrayA[[j]].arrayB[[i]].arrayA[[j]], {i, n}, {j, m}]];
```

And suppose I know the result of this {n,m} matrix, given by:

```
knownResult = Array[res, Dimensions[resultingArray]]
```

How can I back-calculate (any) arrays arrayA and arrayB to reproduce the result? I know the mapping won't be unique since there's a loss of information by computing the dot product, but that's fine - I just need any arrays which will reproduce this. Only caveat being the dimensions need to be respected i.e. arrayA should have dimensions {m,3} and arrayB should have dimensions {n,3,3}.

---

### Attempt at Solution

I've had some luck by using a diagonal arrayB for small {n,m} with Solve:

```
arrayBDiag = DiagonalMatrix@*Diagonal /@ Array[b, {n, 3, 3}];
resultingArrayDiag = Simplify[Table[arrayA[[j]].arrayBDiag[[i]].arrayA[[j]], {i, n}, {j, m}]];
vars = Join @@ (Cases[Flatten[#], Except[0]] & /@ {arrayA, arrayBDiag})
```

With the below evaluating to True:

```
{exampleArrayA, exampleArrayB} =
Block[{sol = Quiet@Solve[
  Thread[Flatten[knownResult] == Flatten[resultingArrayDiag]], 
  vars][[1]], nonUnique},
nonUnique = DeleteCases[vars, Alternatives @@ First /@ sol];
Simplify[{arrayA, arrayBDiag} //. 
Join[Thread[nonUnique -> Range[Length[nonUnique]]], sol]]];
knownResult == Simplify[Table[exampleArrayA[[j]].exampleArrayB[[i]].exampleArrayA[[j]], {i, 
n}, {j, m}]]
```

However, this doesn't scale for large n and m. I was hoping to find an elegant solution using some sort of decomposition (perhaps SVD?), but I've had no luck so far.

---

### Edit 1

Allowing for a non-exact answer, another idea might be to minimize the total error for the various coefficients. For a numeric array this does work, however both the timing and (more worrying) the error scale poorly..

```
NMinimize[
Total[(RandomReal[{0, 1}, Dimensions[resultingArrayDiag]] - 
 resultingArrayDiag)^2, 2],
Join @@ (Cases[Flatten[#], Except[0]] & /@ {arrayA, arrayBDiag})]
```

Comment: What is the range of "large" $n$ and $m$ in your problem?

Comment: They're in the thousands - e.g. n =1440 and m=2927 for one particular case.